# Saving a Timeout within the Element

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I created a `<select multiple>` with dropdown (if you are interested in the full code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MiXT4PE/pen/OYLRpz) or snippet at the bottom) with a helper-function (simplified version below) handling the blur-event (focus-loss of the input aka clicking somewhere else):

```
function blur(element) {
    clearTimeout(eval(element.dataset.timer));
    element.dataset.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (activeElement !== el)
            el.style.display = "none";
    }, 200).toString();
}
```

It creates a timeout and stores it within the [dataset-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) of the element. As this property only accepts Strings it is converted by `toString()` and converted back by `eval()` when clearing the previous timer. This is NOT necessary in the sense that it works perfectly fine when not doing the conversion and evaluation like that:

```
function blur(element) {
    clearTimeout(element.dataset.timer);
    element.dataset.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (activeElement !== el)
            el.style.display = "none";
    }, 200);
}
```

Either way it feels like a hack and I also know that `eval()` should not be used which is why I wonder how I should solve this problem instead. I already [showed my code to CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/219792/191994) specifically mentioning the function but no one complained about it. This can't be the correct way of doing this, can it?

Here is a snippet of the full code if relevant:

```js
convertSelect("001", "Options");

function convertSelect(el_id, name) {
    let el = document.getElementById(el_id),
        opts = Array.from(el.options);

    let input_el = document.createElement('input');
    input_el.setAttribute('id', el_id + '_input');
    input_el.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input_el.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
    input_el.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    input_el.setAttribute('style', `width:${el.offsetWidth}px`);
    input_el.addEventListener('focus', () => document.getElementById(el_id + '_span').style.display = "");
    input_el.addEventListener('blur', () => blur(el_id));
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(input_el, el.nextSibling);

    let span_el = document.createElement('span');
    span_el.setAttribute('id', el_id + '_span');
    span_el.setAttribute('style', `min-width:${(input_el.offsetWidth + 50)}px;margin-top:${input_el.offsetHeight}px;margin-left:-${input_el.offsetWidth}px;position:absolute;border:1px solid grey;display:none;z-index:9999;text-align:left;background:white;max-height:130px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;`);
    span_el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => blur(el_id));
    span_el.addEventListener('click', () => document.getElementById(el_id + '_input').focus());
    input_el.parentNode.insertBefore(span_el, input_el.nextSibling);

    opts.forEach(opt => {
        let i = opts.indexOf(opt);

        let temp_label = document.createElement('label');
        temp_label.setAttribute('for', el_id + '_' + i);

        let temp_input = document.createElement('input');
        temp_input.setAttribute('style', 'width:auto;');
        temp_input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        temp_input.setAttribute('id', el_id + '_' + i);
        temp_input.checked = opt.selected;
        temp_input.disabled = opt.disabled || el.disabled;
        temp_input.addEventListener('change', () => check(el_id, name));

        temp_label.appendChild(temp_input);
        temp_label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(opt.textContent));
        span_el.appendChild(temp_label);
    });
    el.style.display = 'none';
    check(el_id, name);
}


function blur(el_id) {
    let el = document.getElementById(el_id);
    clearTimeout(el.dataset.timer);
    el.dataset.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (document.activeElement.id !== el_id + '_input' && document.activeElement.id !== el_id + '_span')
            document.getElementById(el_id + '_span').style.display = "none";
    }, 200);
}

function check(el_id, name) {
    let el = document.getElementById(el_id),
        opts = Array.from(el.options),
        select_qty = 0,
        select_name;

    opts.forEach(opt => {
        let i = opts.indexOf(opt),
            checkbox = document.getElementById(`${el_id}_${i}`);

        el.options[i].selected = checkbox.checked;
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            select_name = checkbox.parentElement.childNodes[1].textContent;
            select_qty++;
        }
        document.getElementById(`${el_id}_input`).value = select_qty < 1 ? '' : (select_qty > 1 ? `${select_qty} ${name}` : select_name);
    });

    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }));
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<select id="001" multiple>
  <option value="2">Option Two</option>
  <option value="4">Option Four</option>
  <option value="6">Option Six</option>
  <option value="8" disabled>Disabled Option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not sure why you feel the second version is a hack,..  But if you want to make sure it's an integer, instead of `eval` , use `parseInt` instead.

Comment: @Keith `setTimeout().toString()` somehow seems like information loss to me. You are right: `parseInt()` is way better here. Thank you for this suggestion

Comment: No need to delete question, for people who have come from a statically compiled language, it can really feel Alien how Javascript loose boxing & unboxing is performed.  I'll knock up an answer that might feel more natural..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have come from a statically compiled language, sometimes JavaScripts loose boxing / unboxing of types can feel alien. Your example shouldn't have any issues though.

However, there are other ways to store data on an element, and if your data gets more complicated, storing on a data-attribute, might not be the best idea.

---

One option, is just an extension of you data-attribute idea. You could use JSON to serialize your data:

```
element.dataset.options = JSON.stringify({timerId: setTimeout(....)});
```

One disadvantage of the above is that the types you can store are limited to what JSON can serialize, but things like strings / integers / arrays etc. work nicely.

---

Elements in JavaScript are just like any other object. So in theory you could just store as a property:

```
element._mytimerid = setTimeout(...`,
```

With this approach you have to be careful on what you called the property.

---

Closures are a popular choice:

```
function setupBlur() {
  var timerId = null;
  element.onBlur = function () {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(.....
  }
}

setupBlur();
```

You can also use the above inside an IIFE, to save calling setupBlur:

```
(function () { 
  var timerId = null;
  element.onBlur = function () {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(.....
}());
```

---

A more modern way to store data on a element is using a WeakMap:

```
const timerIds = new WeakMap();
.....
const timerId = timerIds.get(element);
clearTimeout(timerId);
timerIds.set(element, setTimer(.....));
```

Comment: No problem, I remember things not feeling right when I first started using JS.  I first started using Typescript because of this, but nowadays I feel more comfortable with it's loose nature. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe create a global timer object where you store the timeout(s) with consecutive keys and store just the key in the dataset?
Kind of like:

```
var timersObj = {};
//store timeout in object
timersObj["timerIndex_0"] = setTimeout(() => {
        if (activeElement !== el)
            el.style.display = "none";
    }, 200)
element.dataset.timer = "timerIndex_0";
//clear timeout by key
clearTimeout(timersObj[element.dataset.timer])
```

Comment: Important to note, `timerObj` need to be defined in the parent scope